# Sound file will not play using playsound module python error 259

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-playsound

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound("1.mp3")
```

The code above using the playsound module results in the following errors. How to resolve?

```
    Error 259 for command:
        play 1.mp3 wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.

    Error 263 for command:
        close 1.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: 1.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itsra\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    playsound("1.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\itsra\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\playsound.py", line 73, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'play {}{}'.format(sound, ' wait' if block else ''))
  File "C:\Users\itsra\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 259 for command:
        play 1.mp3 wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
```

Comment: Are the python script and `1.mp3` are in the same folder?

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder.

Comment: Are you having this problem with other mp3 files or just this one?

Answer (score 15):

I also got the same problem. Try downgrading playsound version.
Use

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem. Try converting into a wav file. It worked for me and I think the problem is because of the lack of information about the bit rate of the music in the file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9X2P.png)

Answer (score 0):

This version of Pyaudio worked for me :
`pip install playsound==1.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I got this error & downgraded to 1.2.2 (from 1.3.0) as suggested in other comments & it worked.

**Solution 2:**

The other solution that I tried (v 1.3.0) is to rename the file & it worked.

**I get the error if file name =** "lost_money.mp3" or "money_lost.mp3"

**But not:** "lost money.mp3" or "transaction_failed.mp3" or "made_profit.mp3"

Comment: yes but it works when u reinstall version 1.3 after 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

playsound library is simple to use but it does not support some audio formats. This solution works for all type of formats

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import time
import miniaudio

file='1.mp3'
audio = MP3(file)
length=audio.info.length
stream = miniaudio.stream_file(file)

with miniaudio.PlaybackDevice() as device:
    device.start(stream)
    print('playing')
    time.sleep(length)
```