# Error 259 on python playsound() unable to sound

Tags: python, windows, python-playsound

I Saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065485/sound-file-will-not-play-using-playsound-module-python-error-259) here. But my file is already in wav. My code is a timer which plays sound after timer ends using threading. It wasn't working there, then I tried it in different file which just had the file and library:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('alarm.wav')
```

When I do this following error occurs:

```
Error 259 for command:
        play alarm.wav wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 259 for command:
        play alarm.wav wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
```

But when I give the path:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('path/to/alarm.wav')
```

the following error occurs in a pop box (SyntaxError):

```
(unicode error)some stuff after that
```

I'm on Windows and I tried it on IDLE and by double clicking the file (Python3.7.3).

If it helps, it works on a different device (both have same Python versions).

Comment: do you use Windows on other device? As I know `playsound` use system program `play` to run it and it may need to install it manually - it is not Python module but normal .exe file - on my Linux `play` runs [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). Other problem can be `/` in path - on Linux it may work but Windows may need `\ ` or `\\ `

Comment: Yeah, I use windows on both devices. I installed it via pip command and its installed in the correct location.I `\\` used this but said unicode codec error

Comment: you have to use \\  because single \ has special meaning in strings - even in path - like `\n` for new line, `\t` for tab, `\u...` for unicode, etc. OR you have to use prefix `r` for `raw` string - `r"C:\full\path\to\file.wav"`

Comment: What is the playsound version? I got the same error too. I tried downgrading playsound version to 1.2.2. Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Run this in CMD or any such terminal:

`pip install playsound==1.2.2`

Downgrading the version works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I try to use code:

```
playsound(u"path/to/alarm.wav")
```

and it works well for me (python 3.9.5, playsound 1.3.0, windows 11 platform)

Comment: what version of playsound are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For me, for some reason playsound doesn't work on pycharm, no matter the version, but IT WORKS ON IDLE. Try that.
Maybe it's because on pycharm .mp3 file extensions aren't "associated with any file type." Whatever the reason, running playsound on IDLE instead of pycharm worked for me, hope it works for you! (also, I used playsound version 1.2.2)